# Can somebody with link can edit exe or APK files on google driver?

Tags: file-sharing, google-drive, internet-security

If I share an EXE or APK file with the option of editing on Google Drive, can anyone actually change it? I mean the file?

Comment: Have you tried it?

Comment: Probably not, those files aren't meant to be modified anyways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes if it's editable it can be changed e.g. by [uploading a new version](https://www.labnol.org/internet/update-files-in-google-drive/28928/).

Comment: I read your link but it's look like only owner of the file can upload a new version

Comment: @brd90 no, it works with files from other users as well, just try it.

Comment: Oh i see. Tell me one more thing, where can i check if somebody change the version? Any log or smth

Comment: @brd90 at the same place where you upload a new version, again, just give it a try